# Error message - Unfortunately, MyAppName has stopped

Tags: android

I'm making very simple an application contains 38 image, when I run the application I got this message:

Unfortunately, ***MyAppName*** has stopped.

when I click **OK** the application go back work, Then next few pages do the same thing.

My application run without need connect to the internet ,

**Here is my LogCat:**

Out of memory on a 12566540-byte allocation.
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.Web.myappname/com.Web.myappname.A4}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class

I using the image in background.

**This is XML file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:android1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android1:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/image_01" >

<Button
android1:id="@+id/button1"
android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
android1:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android1:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android1:text="Main"
android1:textStyle="bold"
tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

<Button
android1:id="@+id/button2a1"
android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
android1:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android1:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android1:text="Next"
android1:textStyle="bold"
tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**and java file:**

```
package com.web.myappname;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class A1 extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.a1);

    Button main = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    main.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    startActivity(new Intent(A1.this, MainActivity.class));

            }
    });

    Button forward = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2a1);
    forward.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    startActivity(new Intent(A1.this, A2.class));

            }
    });

    }

}
```

Any kind of help or suggestion is much appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: it seems like you hasn't got enough memory for run that application. See the free memory in the phone, than sum all images size and add for it ~2MB. If the image sizes are bigger than the free memory, reduce the images size

Comment: I have 38 pages, Each page contains a picture as a background.

Comment: I don't have image more than 600 KB.

Comment: Is there anyone who is a professional can solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Without code it's very hard to suggest anything.

Your application is crashing because you are loading heavy images without recycling memory. It's always tricks with images. Maybe if you try it on a phone with low memory your application will crash even sooner.

Solution: The best thing to do is use an external good library for loading images. It will take care everything for you and your application will not crash when you don't free memory.

Most commonly used library is https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Comment: Do you think this library help me if I using the image in background??

Comment: Yes, It helps you whenever you are using ImageView.

Comment: But I used ... android:background="@drawable/image_01"

Comment: I try this but not work:  
ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
        .defaultDisplayImageOptions(null)
        .build();
        ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);

Answer (score 0):

Bitmap image requires a lot of memory and your application got out of memory while loading images. You have to load large bitmap effectively. Please see how to load large bitmap in Android.

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

[Android Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) is also good alternative.

Comment: I try to use load-bitmap but it is complicated.

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful: [android:largeHeap="true"](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#AndroidManifestApplication_largeHeap)

It tells android it would like a larger heap allocation. However Android doesn't have to respect it. This may "fix" your problem however I also believe it is a poor solution.